# How to edit the web.config in application hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I want to change the appsettings value in web.config. When i run the application in the vs development server, everything works fine but when i upload the application on iis it throws the foolowing exception.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCnsn.png

Here is what i have written in the button click event 

  Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

        config.AppSettings.Settings["FirstName"].Value = "Nitin";
        config.AppSettings.Settings["LastName"].Value = "Singh";
        config.Save();

While in my web.config i have created the appsettings as follows

 <appSettings>
    <add key="FirstName" value="Sikandar" />
    <add key="LastName" value="Bharti" />
    <add key="Adress" value="Lucknow" />
  </appSettings>
```

It seems to me  that this is the problem of iis security. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because the user your site is running as under Windows permissions can't write to that directory.  (I would keep things that way.)

Perhaps you could re-write the code which saves to web.config to save to an xml file in the app_data folder or use cookies or add support for a database.